# Cannot reply to interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I cannot reply to a reaction if the user has already reported the message.

I get this error:

```
Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
```

My Code:

Note: I have all modules imported, this code is a snippet of the file.

```js
let reported = [];

collector.on("collect", async interaction => {
    if (interaction.user.id === message.author.id) {
        // this message works
        const error = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(client.config_embeds.error)
            .setDescription(`${emoji.error} You cannot report yourself!`)

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [error], ephemeral: true });
        return;
    }

    await interaction.deferUpdate();

    if (interaction.customId === `report - ${message.id} `) {
        if (reported.includes(interaction.user.id)) {
            // this message doesnt send
            const error = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor(client.config_embeds.error)
                .setDescription(`${emoji.error} You have already reported this message!`)

            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [error], ephemeral: true });
            return;
        }

        reported.push(interaction.user.id);

        const reportChannel = await client.channels.cache.get("channel_id");

        // this message works
        const report = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(client.config_embeds.error)
            .setAuthor({ name: message.author.tag, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true }), url: `https://discord.com/users/${message.author.id}` })
            .setDescription(message.content)
            .setFooter({ text: `Reported by: ${interaction.user.tag}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true }), url: `https://discord.com/users/${interaction.user.id}` })

        const jumpBtn = new Discord.ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new Discord.ButtonBuilder()
                    .setStyle(Discord.ButtonStyle.Link)
                    .setLabel("Jump to Message")
                    .setURL(message.url)
            )

        reportChannel.send({ embeds: [report], components: [jumpBtn] });
    }
})
```

I was expecting when the message is reported once it adds it to the array which it does, but then if they try report it again it sends hidden message saying they cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't respond to the same interaction more than once. (AKA calling `deferUpdate()`, `reply()`, etc).

After the line `await interaction.deferUpdate();`, you can use `interaction.editReply()` instead of `interaction.reply()` to respond to the command.

[docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=editReply)